# Fabric.js: How to serialize/deserialize some global data? How to extend the canvas object?

Tags: serialization, metadata, fabricjs

How can I add additional properties to the canvas object so that they get serialized/deserialized? E.g. I'd like to store a *name* for the data that I get with canvas.toJSON() and that I store on the server-side.

Does it make sense to extend the canvas this way? Or would you recommend to create a "meta object" that contains my additianal data and one property for the canvas json?

Comment: I would suggest reading the official introduction about the serialization http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#serialization. You might find it useful and find the answer to your question.

Comment: @AdamM. I read it already, but it is more about objects (rect, text, ..) and not about the canvas, afaik. I didn't know that the serialization also refers to the canvas object, as shkaper has pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array with additional properties into `Canvas.toJSON()` method like this:

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')
canvas.myProp = 'MyCanvas'

const serializedCanvas = canvas.toJSON(['myProp'])
console.log(serializedCanvas.myProp) // 'MyCanvas'
```

Note that this array is also passed into every object's `_toObject()` method during the serialization, so it makes sense to keep the custom property list to a minimum.

Comment: Seems to work. Which problem might arise with the array?

Comment: @robsch Consider an example: `fabric.Object` has a property named `matrixCache`. By default, it is left out during serialization. However, if you were to name your custom `Canvas` property `matrixCache` and call `canvas.toJSON(['matrixCache'])`, all the objects would end up having their own `matrixCache`s included in their respective serialized versions. I imagine it won't hurt in most cases, although it's definitely something to be aware of.

Comment: I think I understood that already, but I didn't know that it also works with `fabric.Canvas`, which is not derived from `fabric.Object`. Conclusion: if I specify a property name in `canvas.toJSON()` it will be used for the canvas object and the single element objects. Probable also when they are nested in groups.

Comment: @robsch Correct